# python-for-android send an email

Tags: android, python

I am trying to create an app for Android using python-for-android. I want my app to send me an xls file by email. to do so I am using smtplib:

```
smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.login('myadress@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
s.sendmail('myadress@gmail.com', 'to@gmail.com', message)
s.close()
```

when I run my app from my android phone I have this error message:

> Error in starttls, No SSL support include in this python, I have try with or without starttls and ehlo but no joy. I have try to import ssl.py manually but I come across more problem...

How can I set up a SSL interpreter on the android phone? or is there another solution to send an email?

I am using:

- Android 4.1.2
- Python 2.7
- Android SDK 22.2.1
- API 18

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Android below JellyBean supports SSL. I tried to use an app that required SSL an it refused to connect.

Comment: So is there another way for sending a file using python-for-android?